# ASP.Net 5: Solution architecture

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my previous ASP developments, I used to separate my solution in multiple projects, each one having a specific roles:

1. mySolution.Web with the views, controllers, JS, CSS
2. mySolution.Data.DAL to define the detabase mapping and repositories
3. mySolution.Data.Domain to define the entities and domains
4. mySolution.Data.Services for services such as email...
5. Tests...
6. ....

What would be your suggestion considering the new ASP.Net 5 tree view:

From:

```
 src
       Web
          Controllers
          Migrations ???
          Models
          Services
          ViewModels
          Views
```

to

```
src
   Web
      Controllers
      Migrations ???  
      ViewModels
      Views
   Data.DAL
      Mapping
      Repositories
   Data.Domain
      Entities
      Models
   Services
      Services
```

Does it make sense? Is it still in the spirit of this new ASP.Net 5 or we should better stick with one dedicated project?

Concerning the other projects (not .Web), I have used Class library package instead of class library dll, is it more relevant for ASP.net 5 projects or the only benefit is to create a Nuget package instead of a .dll file?

Thanks

Sylvain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the size of your project. If the project is small I should go for the first one.

I don't think you should make use of class libary dll. Mixing dnx project with the old projects will give you more trouble with testing and deploying.

Important is that you create the following structure
--src
      project1
      project2
--test
      project1.test
      project2.test

A good source how projects can be setup is

- https://github.com/aspnet.

Example projects

- https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore
- https://github.com/aspnet/live.asp.net

Microsoft use .shade files and korebuild for building, testing, packaging and deploying. You can used that but you can also setup your own.

There is almost no documentation about .shade file and korebuild.

Comment: Thanks @Thom for that, I am a bit abashed with this new architecture and wanted to get some feedback.